# For loop ignore my first item

Tags: r

I would be appreciative if you can help me with the following two issues:

1. The 'for' loop below ignores my first looping item. The code below is a small part of my program. Here, I am iterating the object 'num' and looping through 'mySet' using the function 'Grep' which flags certain items from mySet.

The 'for' loop works except at the first element '0' of the 'num' object. Consequently, it does not find any item that starts with '0' in mySet.

```
num <- c(0,2,4,6,8,10,15,20,30,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,80,85,90,92,94,96,98,100)
mySet <- c("0.C.A", "2.C.A", "4.C.A", "6.C.A", "8.C.A", "10.C.A", "15.C.A", "20.C.A",
           "30.C.A", "40.C.A", "45.C.A", "50.C.A", "55.C.A", "60.C.A", "65.C.A", "70.C.A",
           "80.C.A", "85.C.A", "90.C.A", "92.C.A", "94.C.A", "96.C.A", "98.C.A", "100.C.A")
varLoop <- c()
Grep <- function(num)grep(paste("^" , num, "\\.", sep=""), mySet, value = TRUE)
for(i in num){
    varLoop[i] <- Grep(i)
    print(varLoop[i])}
```

1. The second issue is an incomplete output and warnings if I modify the script as follows. The warning is: 'number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length'. The incomplete out put does not include any of the items ending with the letter B

The script below produces the problem:

```
num <- rep(c(0,2,4,6,8,10,15,20,30,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,80,85,90,92,94,96,98,100), 2)
mySet <- c("0.C.A", "2.C.A", "4.C.A", "6.C.A", "8.C.A", "10.C.A", "15.C.A", "20.C.A",
           "30.C.A", "40.C.A", "45.C.A", "50.C.A", "55.C.A", "60.C.A", "65.C.A", "70.C.A",
           "80.C.A", "85.C.A", "90.C.A", "92.C.A", "94.C.A", "96.C.A", "98.C.A", "100.C.A",
           "0.C.B", "2.C.B", "4.C.B", "6.C.B", "8.C.B", "10.C.B", "15.C.B", "20.C.B",
           "30.C.B", "40.C.B", "45.C.B", "50.C.B", "55.C.B", "60.C.B", "65.C.B", "70.C.B",
           "80.C.B", "85.C.B", "90.C.B", "92.C.B", "94.C.B", "96.C.B", "98.C.B", "100.C.B")
varLoop <- c()
Grep <- function(num)grep(paste("^" , num, "\\.", sep=""), mySet, value = TRUE)
for(i in num){
    varLoop[i] <- Grep(i)
    print(varLoop[i])}
```

Thank you in advance,
Ragy Isaac

Comment: Indexing starts from 1, not 0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135325/why-do-vector-indices-in-r-start-with-1-instead-of-0

Comment: ... Which means that when `varLoop[0] <- Grep(0)` runs, your result won't be stored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `R`, indexing starts from `1` not `0`

```
x <- 1:5
x[0] 
## integer(0)
```

The idiomatic approach would be to do something like `seq_along` and then index `num` with the results.

You are in [the second circle of R Hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) growing your object within the loop.

I think here, however something `sapply` will help simplify your code

```
sapply(num, Grep)
```