# What is the point of allowing a zero index when subsetting?

Tags: r, subset

Since R vector indices start at 1, what is the point of allowing indexing with zero:

```
rivers[0]
#numeric(0)
```

This returns a zero length vector.  Why not an error?  How is this useful?

Comment: I dont understand the question, do you mean [Why do vector indices in R start with 1, instead of 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135325/why-do-vector-indices-in-r-start-with-1-instead-of-0)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not trying to solve a programming problem

Answer (score 8):

There aren't many use cases that crop up typically.  I actually have one in the context of a **[package I'm developing for template based validations](https://github.com/brodieG/alike)**.  For example, if I want to create a template of the `iris` data frame, I can use:

```
iris[0, ]
```

Produces (note, showing output of `str(iris[0, ])`):

```
'data.frame': 0 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num 
 $ Sepal.Width : num 
 $ Petal.Length: num 
 $ Petal.Width : num 
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..:
```

I've essentially abstracted the structure of the data frame.  I have all the column definitions, but none of the data.

Comment: I'd also add that it gives a non-error transition point between negative and positive indexing, which can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's what the language definition [specifies](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors):

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

Comment: so the point is "because that's what the specs say"? -1

Comment: @eddi, please note the question was edited a couple of times, and under one of the edits this answer was actually spot on.

Comment: @BrodieG lol, so it was a spot on answer when the answerer changed the "meaning of the question", where I'm quoting you?

Comment: @eddi, yes, I just felt bad that my changing the question back to what I think is the intended original meaning made this answer look particularly bad when in reality it may have just been a misunderstanding of the original question, which was in need of some editing.

Comment: @eddi I've tried to salvage a question that strongly suffered from lack of language skills. Maybe the current wording is what OP intended, maybe not. It doesn't look like they gave feedback.