# Why is it valid to slice a vector starting with index zero?

Tags: r

```
v <- 1:10
```

So I accidentally discovered that:

```
v[0:10] == v[1:10]
```

output:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How? First of all, I thought that R indices start with 1?

Comment: Indexes at zero are basically just ignored. You could also index with negative numbers and these don't start with 1 either.

Comment: It's the same as `c(NULL, 1:10) == 1:10`

Comment: @mickey: I don't think you can mix negative and positive indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) (section 3.4.1, "Indexing by vectors", "Integer"):

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

[Another SO question asks "why is this useful"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814918/what-is-the-point-of-allowing-a-zero-index-when-subsetting), without many satisfying answers: this is an interesting question, but seems on-topic for `r-devel@r-project.org` rather than SO ...